# Function find(string,string) is not applicable for (string,string[])

Tags: arrays, string, find

Below is my code. However I keep getting an error that states "Function find(string,string) is not applicable for the arguments (string,string[])". This is happening on the nameArray and timeArray variables. How can I fix this?

`function void getName(string[] goalsArray, integer idx){
    string name;
    string time;

```
string[] nameRegEx = find($in.0.Goals,"([\\x41-\\x5A\\x8A\\x8C\\x8E\\x9F\\xC0-\\xDD][\\x61-\\x7A\\x9A\\xE0-\\xFF]+ )+");
string[] timeRegEx = find($in.0.Goals,"[0-9]+['|\\+0-9]+");

string[] nameArray = find(goalsArray[idx], nameRegEx);
string[] timeArray = find(goalsArray[idx], timeRegEx);


if(length(nameArray)>0)name = nameArray[0];
else name ="";

if(length(timeArray)>0)time = timeArray[0];
else time ="";

if(length(name)>0){
    string[]first_and_last = split(name, " ");
    $out.0.Player_FirstName=first_and_last[0];

if(length(first_and_last)>1)$out.0.Player_LastName = first_and_last[1];

else $out.0.Player_LastName = "n/a";
}

else if(length(time)>1){
    getName(goalsArray,idx-1);
}

else{
    $out.0.Player_FirstName ="n/a";
    $out.0.Player_LastName = "n/a";
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

This is array of strings : `string[] nameRegEx`

Here you try to call method `find` with parameters `string` and `array of strings` : `find(goalsArray[idx], nameRegEx);`

Apparently such method does not exist, the closest method with same name is method `find`, which takes two `string`s as arguments